localhost refused to connect. While working with nextjs
npm run dev    

> doctor-appointment-booking-web-app@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

  ▲ Next.js 14.2.3
  - Local:        http://localhost:3000
  - Environments: .env.local

 ✓ Starting...
[Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, readlink 'C:\Users\H\OneDrive\Desktop\MERN-MajorProject\doctor-appointment-booking-web-app\.next\static\chunks\main-app.js'] {
  errno: -4094,
  code: 'UNKNOWN',
  syscall: 'readlink',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\H\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MERN-MajorProject\\doctor-appointment-booking-web-app\\.next\\static\\chunks\\main-app.js'
}

HOW do i solve this error , i am working on a next js web app ??
[http://localhost:3000/](https://i.sstatic.net/XWe8nalc.png)
I have used Strapi API and was connectiing it to the web app .

Looks like this issue was referenced prior 1.
Assuming you have already tried npm build and npm update then npm run dev with no resolution:

Stop any nodejs process for the project
Close the code editor you are working in and reopen it
Delete the .next folder in your project directory
Run npm cache clear --force
Close the code editor you are working in and reopen it
run npm run dev

Considering npm, npm cache clear is a alias for npm cache clean. "Cleaning" the cache folder consists of removing all data out of it. Note this is usually not necessary as npm's cache is typically resistant to data corruption due to self healing.
npm stores cache data in directory within the configured cache typically named _cacache. This will manage local key and content address caches. Due to its ability for concurrency; running the subcommand of --force is required for clean to run 7.24.2 (legacy) and up.
If this does not work it could potentially be antivirus killing your dev server on http://localhost:3000. Ensure your server is running with a exception added to your firewall.
References:
2


Install latest Node Version

Fresh Install Next.JS


